# One Filter for Two models

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm new to a Django REST Framework, so I have one question.

I have two **models**:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(FoodCategory)
    .....

class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    ri_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ri_number = models.IntegerField()
    ingredient_id = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    .....
```

Serializer.py:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers. ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('recipe_id', 'title', 'category',....)

class RecipeIngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredients
        fields = ('ri_id', 'recipe_id', 'ri_number', 'ingredient_id', ...)
```

The output of each:

```
{"recipe_id":1,"title":"Recipe1","category":1, ....} # Recipe

[{"ri_id":15,"recipe_id":1,"ri_number":1,"ingredient_id":6,},
{"ri_id":16,"recipe_id":1,"ri_number":2,"ingredient_id":7,....}] # RecipeIngredients
```

There is a question: Can I make a **Recipe** query filtering by **category**(Recipe model) and, for example **Ingredients' id** (RecipeIngredients model), so that will be one query?

For example:

> http://127.0.0.1/api/recipes?category=category_name&ingredients=[ingred_list]

The main problem, that **category** field is in Recipe model, but **ingredients' id** is in RecipeIngredients model, but each ingredient refers to recipe id.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.How do you exactly want to filter?

Comment: Thank you for answer.
For example, I want to show all recipes which are in **Category** [category_name] and with specific list of **ingredients**. 
htttp://127.0.0.1/api/recipes?category=meals&ingredients=[ingredients/ingredient].
Something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset()` method in your view. We first get the list of `recipe_ids` having `ingredient_id` values as either of the `ingredient_id` value received from the query params. Then we filter all the recipes having `recipe_id` value as the values in `recipe_ids` and `category` as the `category` received in the query param.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    category = self.request.query_params['category']
    ingredient_ids = self.request.query_params['ingredients[]'] # [] because getting multiple values for a same key
    recipe_ids = RecipeIngredients.objects.filter(ingredient_id__in=ingredient_ids).values_list('recipe_id', flat=True)
    return Recipe.objects.filter(recipe_id__in=recipe_ids, category=category)
```